# Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized

Tags: android, soundpool

This code

```
soundPool.release();
soundPool = null;
```

sometimes produces this error:

```
Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
    at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub$Proxy.stopWatchingMode(IAppOpsService.java:431)
    at android.media.SoundPool.release(SoundPool.java:195)
    at android.media.SoundPool.finalize(SoundPool.java:204)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:217)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:200)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: If it happens just *sometimes*, what about wrapping it in `try-catch` block?

Comment: @activity, Share more code for brief understanding

Answer (score 4):

So I think this might be an Android bug. Looks suspiciously like this issue, which is marked as fixed in a "future version": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37138597